# Doubt in Integration a function on a $k$ - cell.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $I^k$ is a $k$-cell in $R^k$, consisting of all $X = (x_1, ... , x_k)$
such that $a_i \le  x_i \le b_i (i = 1, \cdots , k)$,

$I^j$ is the $j$-cell in $R^j$ defined by the first $j$ inequalities, and $f$ is a real continuous function on $I^k$. (**What does real continuous function in this case mean?- A function $f:I^k \to \mathbb{R}$?**)

Put $f = f_k$, and define $f_{k-1}$  on $I^{k-1}$ by

$$f_{k-1}(x_1, \cdots , x_{k-1}) = \int_{a_k}^{b_k}h(x_1,\cdots, x_{k-1}, x_k) d_{x_k}\cdots (**)$$.

let us introduce the temporary notation $L(f)$ for the integral (**) and $L'(f)$ for the result obtained by carrying out the k integrations in some other order.

For every $f \in \mathbb{C}(I^k), L(f) = L'(f)$

**Proof**: If $h(x) = h_1(x_1)\cdots h_k(x_k)$,(**I really don't understand how and why are we considering such a function h(x)**) where $h_j \in \mathbb{C}([a_i, b_i])$,

$L(h) = \prod_{i = 1}^k \int_{a_i}^{b_i} h_i(x_i) d_{x_i} = L'(h)$. (**How are we getting this?**)
Put $V = \prod_{i=1}^k(b_i-a_i)$

If $f \in \mathbb{C}(I^k)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $g \in \mathbb{A} $ such
that $||f - g|| < \epsilon/ V$, where $||f||$ is defined as max $|f(x)|$ ($x \in I^k$). Then
$|L(f-g)| < \epsilon$, $|L'(f-g)|< \epsilon$,(** I don't understand this calculation also**) and since

$L(f) - L'(f) = L(f - g) + L'(g - f)$,
we conclude that $L(f) - L'(f)  < 2\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, a real continuous function on a topological space $X$ is a continuous function $X\to\Bbb R$.
2. We consider the set $\Bbb A$ of functions of this specific form $h(x)=\prod_i h_i(x_i)$ for two reasons: first, we can calculate their integrals easily and they readily satisfy the statement (see point 3) and second, these functions are *dense* among all real functions on $I^k$. This second one is not a trivial statement, presumably proved beforehand, utilizing that $I^k$ is compact.
3. For clarity, let's verify it for $k=2$. The same (or induction) applies for arbitrary $k$.
   $$\int_{I^k}h_1(x_1)h_2(x_2)\,d(x_1,x_2)=\int_{a_1}^{b_1}\!\!\int_{a_2}^{b_2} h_1(x_1)h_2(x_2)\,dx_2dx_1=
   \int_{a_1}^{b_1}\left(h_1(x_1)\cdot \int_{a_2}^{b_2} h_2(x_2)\,dx_2\right)\,dx_1=\left(\int_{a_2}^{b_2} h_2(x_2)\,dx_2\right)\cdot\int_{a_1}^{b_1}h_1(x_1)\,dx_1$$
4. It's using the claim that our special functions in 2. are in fact *dense* among all continuous real functions, which means exactly that for any $f\in C(I^k)$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there's a function $g\in\Bbb A$ (of the special form) such that $\|f-g\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: How are you proceeding with step $3$?$
\int_{a_1}^{b_1}\left(h_1(x_1)\cdot \int_{a_2}^{b_2} h_2(x_2)\,dx_2\right)\,dx_1=\left(\int_{a_2}^{b_2} h_2(x_2)\,dx_2\right)\cdot\int_{a_1}^{b_1}h_1(x_1)\,dx_1$?

Comment: In step $4$ I understood that $||f-g|| < \epsilon/V$ but I don't understand that how does it imply that $L(f-g)<\epsilon$ and $L'(f-g) <\epsilon$?

Comment: 3. Consider first the internal integral $dx_2$. Then $h(x_1)$ is constant for each fixed $x_1$, so it can be extracted outside the inner integral. Then the constant $\int_{a_2}^{b_2}h(x_2)\,dx_2$ is extracted similarly from the outer integral. 4. If the order of $x_i$'s is permuted, the integral of $g\in\Bbb A$ doesn't change.

Comment: Since $h_1(x_1)$ is a function in $x_1$ only and $h_2(x_2)$ is a function in $x_2$ only then we can claim that $L(h) = L'(h)$ . Is this correct? Now we are choosing $g$ such that $||f-g|| < \epsilon/V$ then how does it imply that $L(f-g) < \epsilon$?

Comment: $M:=\|f-g\|=\max_{I^k}|f-g|$ then $\int_{I^k}(f-g)\le\int_{I^k}|f-g|\le\int_{I^k}M=M\cdot V$ where $V=\prod_i(b_i-a_i)=\int_{I^k}1$. Yes, for elements of $\Bbb A$ the statement is straightforward (using 3.). But it's also true for any continuous function, that's being proved here.